# How can I multiply each element in vector by all elements of another vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

For example, I have the first vector [2x1]:

```
A = 
[1;-1];
```

and the other vector also [2x1]:

```
B = 
[7;8];
```

I need C to be the results of multiplication of first elemt 1 with 7 and 8, and then -1 with 7 and 8, so the resulted vector c will be [4x1]:

```
C = 
[7; 8;-7;-8];
```

thank you

Comment: @BogdanDoicin , the question as mentioned above, I need to multiply each element of the first vector by all elements of second vector. I need C to be the results of multiplication of first elemt 1 with 7 and 8, and then -1 with 7 and 8. How can I do that  ?

Comment: Transpose one of the vectors, then use element-wise multiplication: `A .* B.'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you particularly want an approach using loops, here is one:

```
A = [1, -1];
B = [7, 8];
m = length(A);
n = length(B);
C = zeros(m * n, 1);
for i = 1:m
  for j = 1:n
    C((i-1) * n + j) = A(i) * B(j);
  end
end
C

C =

 7
 8
-7
-8
```

Personally, I would prefer the `kron` function, too...

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is to calculate the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). In Matlab this is implemented in the function [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html).

```
A =[1;-1];
B = [7;8];
kron(B,A)

ans =

     7
     8
    -7
    -8
```

Comment: Thank you .. yes exactly, but I need to do it using loop, I mean not by the function kron.

Comment: @Gze, if you want to use a loop, you should specify it in the question, so people don't work for nothing.